# How do I optimize my Kiebase build times when I have to 1000+ rules?

Tags: jboss, garbage-collection, drools

I have 1000+ rules in my kiebase and the build time takes around 20-30 seconds. While I was looking at the logs, I saw that there were a ton of GC pauses during this period. Now, the problem is that I need to constantly rebuild the kiebase object since the rules keep getting modified every now and then based on user input.

The other problem is that I have a distributed system so my kiebase needs to exist on multiple systems. So on an update, I have tried serializing it and sending it over, but even deserializing takes a decent amount of time (7-8 seconds). I can see a lot of memory being used here as well and I noticed a few GC pauses.

Is there any optimal way I can build 1000+ rules in a shorter amount of time?
My current code is:

```
        KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
        kfs.write("src/main/resources/drools", rules);
        KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kfs);
        kieBuilder = kieBuilder.buildAll();
```

which takes 30+ seconds for 1000+ rules

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Have you confirmed the issue is actually with Drools and not with however you've configured your garbage collection? Also I would suggest the question about serialization/deserialization be posed separately as an independent question.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried optimizing the GC too much. I'm a bit free at work today, I'll probably go wild and let you know if different configurations make it any quicker.

Comment: Do we have any updates here?

Comment: I accepted the fact that it takes a long time to build and instead tried to make recreating it as a non-blocking background process. I also changed externalised some of the logic so that updates did not require a DRL update.

Comment: @Soccergods Did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: You cannot make it faster, is what I found out. You can either:
1. Build in the background and let that go on for 10 minutes
2. Optimise and compress 1k rules into a much smaller number of rules
2. Move to a different rules engine  (json rules may be quite easy and fast. I haven't explored this).